# Issue with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 onto my machine.
Looks my I have problem with my SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).

For every login it is showing the credential information differently. Please observe the tooltip on below screen shot of different tabs on same SSMS. The user account info is verying always.

For every Windows Authentication Login tooltip is ending with the below user account(fs\c005057(105,128,114,51 etc.....))
Example:
If the below screen shot is not clear, tooltip is showing as below.

```
TAB1(ToolTip) --c:\SQLSErver\CreateSP1\(fs\c005057(105))
TAB2(ToolTip) --c:\SQLSErver\ExeucuteScriptOfSP1\(fs\c005057(128))
TAB3(ToolTip) --c:\SQLSErver\CreateSP2\(fs\c005057(114))
TAB4(ToolTip) --c:\SQLSErver\ExeucuteScriptOfSP1\(fs\c005057(51))
```

Problem, what I'm having now is, If I compile the Storedprocedure in Tab1 and If I executing the SP by giving the parameter in Tab2 in same SSMS, the results are totally unexpected. Suspecting this is the issue. I didn't see this kind of credential information with my previous SSMS, So suspecting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those are the session_id values. Run the following in any query window:

```
SELECT @@SPID;
```

They will match the tooltip. Your unexpected results are caused by a different issue, I guarantee it.

Comment: Aaron Berrand, is this is not an issue?

Comment: Do you know troubleshooting points to resolve the unexpected results issue.

Comment: Each connection to SQL Server has its own session_id (think of it as a process space), so no, this is not an issue. If they all had a single session_id there'd be real problems. I don't know any troubleshooting steps to resolve your 'unexpected results' issue because you've included exactly zero details about that. I would say post a new question with your actual problem (not one about the session_ids you find in the tooltip for your query editor windows).